# JavaEE notification when EJB went offline

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0

is it possible in JavaEE (JBoss AS5.1, EJB 3.0) to get notified when a jboss instance went offline? Specifically I want to receive a notification when a previously looked up ejb is not longer available or is available again (the ejb is not clustered, but that's another story).

My current workaround is to call a method called isAvailable which always returns true, when an exception occures I know the ejb is down. This online check obviously can't be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly, you are wanting to get alerted when a JBoss instance goes down. You would need an external monitoring and alerting tool such as [RHQ](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Home) or [Hawkular](http://www.hawkular.org/) to achieve this.

Having EJBs clustered would help providing high availability. However, you probably still want a motoring and alerting tool to monitor the cluster as well as other resources on the JBoss instances.

If you just care about when the EJB is unavailable and do not want to use an external tool, then you can create a [Service MBean](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html) or a custom [MBean](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Using_JMX_as_a_Microkernel-Writing_JBoss_MBean_Services.html). This way you can create a custom notification tied to your EJB lifecyle .

Please do keep in mind when you decide to upgrade to JBoss AS7 or Wildfly bits, this MBean will have to be changed since the MBean support is quite different in those versions.

Comment: Not necessarily the whole jboss instance, I just need to know when the EJB is no longer available. For example when undeploying the bean, I want to get notified that my proxy to that bean is no longer valid, and, if the bean gets redeployed, is valid again.

Comment: Sure - I edited my post to address your comment. Hope this helps!

Comment: wouldn't this fail if the process crashes or the network cable is unplugged?

Comment: Well if the network cable is unplugged you have bigger problems than your EJBs being unavailable. You will need OS level monitoring process to monitor process segfault alerts and network glitches.